# Can I play a rosbag to simulate data originally recorded from a remote ros master?

Tags: ros, rosbag, master, play

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have data recorded into a bag file on my "local" machine that was generated from a remote ros master.   When I issue a rosbag play command on the file (which I checked and is ok), nothing happened.  When I issue a rostopic echo  for the data I'm looking for, I get "unable to communicate with master", which is true, I want to be able to work on the data at times when I don't have network access to the robot sensors generating it.

Is this possible?  Is it possible some other way to simulate the robot? Do I need to temporarily set ros master to my local machine when I'm doing this?  Or is this what Gazebo can be used for? (even though the data in the bag is relatively simple, just xyz positional data?)

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226164/can-i-play-a-rosbag-to-simulate-data-originally-recorded-from-a-remote-ros-master?/) by [toddwf](https://answers.ros.org/users/25891/toddwf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-02-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [toddwf](https://answers.ros.org/users/25891/toddwf/) on 2016-02-09**:
update: just tried setting ROS_MASTER_URI to https://0.0.0.0:11311 and running roscore instance.  rosbag play  results in unable to contact ros master message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, got it working.  Yes, I need a roscore running.   I had some trouble because I incorrectly set the ROS_HOSTNAME.  Once I got a roscore running, the rosbag play  worked and I was able to run my code against the replayed topic.

Maybe it should've been obvious to me, but I would suggest noting in the docs that a roscore must be running for the bag to properly play.  Since I'm using this to simulate output from a normally remote ros master, it was confusing to me.

---

Originally posted by [toddwf](https://answers.ros.org/users/25891/toddwf/) with karma: 16 on 2016-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0